# Why are my dates off by one day?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a SQL Server table the contents of which I'm displaying in an MVC page using Kendo UI Grid. One of the columns in the table is named RecordDate and is a SQL Server Date type (not a datetime variant).

When my page requests data, I'll retrieve some rows, convert to Json (as shown below) and return them to the client.

```
return Json(resultSet, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

The problem is all the dates are off by one day when displayed in the Kendo grid. I suspect something along the way is assuming the dates are stored as UTC dates (which they are not) and then attempting to convert to local time. However, I have no idea where this is happening, why and how to stop it.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint at `return` line what is the value of the date?

Comment: @CodeNotFound This really isn't a valid test because when I run locally my time zone is the same time zone as the data in the table. This only happens when I run my app in the browser and hitting my code on Azure.

Comment: Have you try different browser? I think the problem when UI Grid convert & shwo the data from json result.

Answer (score 0):

We have recently had a similar issue, there are a number of links which discuss this:

[Stringify modifying dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486476/json-stringify-changes-time-of-date-because-of-utc)

[How to prevent modification of times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18181524/how-do-you-preserve-a-javascript-dates-time-zone-from-browser-to-server-and-ba)

[Server changing dates sent by client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147696/server-side-changes-date-time-sent-by-client)

Notably the best/most acceptable resolution (and one we decided to use) seems to be the use of the [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com/) package to handle dates. However, as you will see throughout the links above, this is open to interpretation.